# How to display pdf through flex 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I am in need of display a pdf through flex 3 to user.Again there is a break point that It is downloaded through file download servlet in byte array format so how I can display this byte array as pdf through flex 3.

any help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check the flex paper project http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/.

It comes with a pdf viewer open source.
Also, you simply need to mention the url of the file download servlet to this pdf viewer, and it will download the pdf and show it the the end user.

Comment: thanks for response, Can you please suggest any sample code to work with flexpaper component.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jasper Report for designing PDf 
check this http://jasperforge.org